# How can I find closed loop dynamics of this system?

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

There is controller, where $a>0$. Now, if $v>0$, then $u = \ddot\theta(t)$ and if $v<0$, then $-u=\ddot\theta(t)$. However, how can I detect whether $v$ is positive or negative?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the PD side of this system is positive or negative"? Do you mean how to know whether $v$ is positive or negative?

Comment: Yes. I mean exactly that.

Comment: Then, please update your question to make it clearer. Note also that you have typos in some of the equations.

Comment: So, here, the only way is to compute the trajectories starting from an initial condition by hand and see how it evolves. The thing is the the closed dynamics are exactly given by $\ddot{\theta}=\mathrm{sign}(-\dot{\theta}+a(\theta_r-\theta))$.